# MongoKitten batch update is atomic or not?

Tags: mongodb, vapor, mongokitten

In Vapor MongoKitten there is an `update` method which accept array of documents. Is update atomically executed or it is method only for convenient use? `MongoDB` doc says:

> When a single write operation modifies multiple documents, the
>   modification of each document is atomic, but the operation as a whole
>   is not atomic and other operations may interleave.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're pointing towards the `update(bulk` method [for multiple update queries](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten/blob/master/4.1/Sources/MongoKitten/Collection/Collection.swift#L273). This function executes a single batch query with multiple update statements. Each update is executed separately but they are submitted in a single batch to MongoDB to limit network load and increase app performance. It's primarily intended for migrations, although there sure are other use cases.

**EDIT:** For the record, this is true for MongoKitten 4. The upcoming MongoKitten 5 release may not support this in the initial version of the high level APIs.